# htaccess remove url prefix, check if file exists, if not send to index.php

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I'm having some difficulties with mod_rewrite, here's what I want to accomplish

1. Remove url prefix that starts by /c/*/
2. After removing the prefix, check if the file exists and if so, use it
3. If the file does not exist, send the request to index.php

In my case, the /c/TENANT_CODE/ is used to identify my tenant on a multi-tenant system. TENANT_CODE will change from one customer to the other.

Examples :

**Access a static image**

http://localhost/c/dev/img/someimage.png

In this case the image exists on the server, so i just want to return the existing image. I want to rewrite my url to http://localhost/img/someimage.png.

**Access a route**

http://localhost/c/dev/some/route

In this case http://localhost/some/route does not exist so I want to send it to the main index.php page so it can be processed by laravel.

Here is what I have so far but it doesn't work

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/c/([^/]*)(/.*)$
RewriteRule ^/c/([^/]*)(/.*)$ $2 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php [QSA,L]
```

Thank you for your comments in advance

Answer (score 0):

Your first rule should be working, but you don't need the condition.

```
RewriteRule ^/c/([^/]*)(/.*)$ $2 [QSA,L]
```

For the rest try using `SCRIPT_FILENAME`:

```
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunately it doesn't work. Still getting same behavior the file that exists can not be found, usingthe /c/tenant/ prefix.